# php mongodb findandmodify not working

Tags: php, mongodb

I am using php and mongodb. I want to use findandmodify. My field is { "_id" : ObjectId("58d37e612d4ffa498b99c2d4"), "userid" : "1234", "active_time" : "hai" }

I want to modify active_time. For example change the value "hai" to "1234"

I am using MongoDB\Driver\Manager.

```
try {
        $mng = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager("mongodb://username:password@localhost:27017/db");
        $userid = '1234';
        $retval = $mng->findAndModify(
        array("userid" => $userid), // searchQuery
        array('$set' => array('active_time' => "kkk")) // UpdateQuery
        );
        $command = new MongoDB\Driver\Command($retval);
        $cursor = $manager->executeCommand('db.online', $command);
} catch (MongoDB\Driver\Exception\Exception $e) {
    $filename = basename(__FILE__);
    echo "The $filename script has experienced an error.\n"; 
    echo "It failed with the following exception:\n";
    echo "Exception:", $e->getMessage(), "\n";
    echo "In file:", $e->getFile(), "\n";
    echo "On line:", $e->getLine(), "\n";       
}
```

It shows the error is

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method MongoDB\Driver\Manager::findAndModify()

in line

```
$retval = $mng->findAndModify(
 array("userid" => $userid), // searchQuery
 array('$set' => array('active_time' => "kkk")) // UpdateQuery
 );
```

How it possible? please help me?

Comment: there is no Function called findAndModify(); http://php.net/manual/en/book.mongodb.php

Comment: I got the answer. see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer. Change the findAndModify to update. The modified code is shown below.

```
$bulk->update(
 array("userid" => '1234'), // searchQuery
 array('$set' => array('active_time' => "kkk")) // UpdateQuery
 );

 $mng->executeBulkWrite("browser.online", $bulk);

 if(!empty($mng)) {
    echo "success";
    } else {
        echo "not";
    }
```